# spim simulator pcspim : error setting value at an address

Tags: assembly, mips, spim, pcspim

Hi I am using spim simulator pcspim and I am trying to set a value at an address using the set value option under the simulator menu.

When I try to set a value which has an msb of 1 for ex. oxb1234567 the value at that address is defaulted to 7fffffff, can anyone explain the reason for this behaviour.

Any help appreciated

Answer (score 0):

In MIPS, addresses starting with 1 (MSB = 1) indicate kernel memory space. You cannot access kernel space from user space (which has MSB = 0) without using syscalls.

Comment: i think u got me wrong .... the msb  of my address is not 1 ...... the msb of my value is 1

Comment: Oh sorry, I read it wrong. Well I don't know why that happens. I might recommend [MARS](http://courses.missouristate.edu/KenVollmar/MARS/) as a better MIPS simulator IMHO.